# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

One of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Much of the FAQ will be somewhat boilerplate: “be nice,” “how to create an account,” “how to ask questions” — it’s all pretty static. Even the sections about “what kind of questions should I (not) ask here?” comes primarily from [the Definition phase of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4?phase=definition).

But the questions you want to discuss in meta are those issues specific to your site that need to be mentioned in the FAQ. It took almost a year to figure out the list of “we want these sort of questions” and “we don’t want these sort of questions” on earlier sites. Area 51 gave you a head start but we should also be working out other FAQ-related issues *specific to our topic and our community*.

See the FAQs of established StackExchange 2.0 sites to see what the FAQ needs to contain and look how they are forming the FAQ on other StackExchange 2.0 beta sites to get some inspiration through examples.

Answer (score 1):

[Off-Topic]

This site is **not** about computer problems that are clearly not related to audio software or hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Posts encouraging piracy will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Off-Topic]

This site is **not** about musical performance.

Comment: Could you please delete this answer and combine the Off-Topic parts? While this makes discussion in the comments more feasible; it will quickly turn this topic in a very long list of all kind of different types of answers, so that we won't have a clear overview anymore... If discussion in the comments turns out of hand another question for that discussion could be made.

Comment: Ok, but I was just following the format of this question on WebApps: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159/what-should-our-faq-contain. It allows people to vote on which items should be included rather than having edit wars.

Comment: Heh... Haven't seen that one, now I don't have a clue what FAQ system would be better. :-(

Answer (score 0):

[On-Topic]

Questions related to the installation, configuration, and operation of audio software.

Comment: I actually think configuration and operation are valid here.  Most of the questions I've asked and answered have been along those lines, usually operation.  I agree that very basic tech-support questions have no place here though (such as installation issues).

Answer (score -1):

[Off-Topic]

Questions about audio and video file formats.

Comment: I'd say, not as a rule.  It could be pertinent in a production setting to discuss lossy vs lossless formats for example.